# Python append lists into lists

Tags: python, list, matrix, append

I am trying to write a function that goes through a matrix.  When a criteria is met, it remembers the location.

I start with an empty list:

```
locations = []
```

As the function goes through the rows, I append the coordinates using:

```
locations.append(x)
locations.append(y)
```

At the end of the function the list looks like so:

```
locations = [xyxyxyxyxyxy]
```

My question is:

**Using append, is it possible to make the list so it follows this format**:

```
locations = [[[xy][xy][xy]][[xy][xy][xy]]]
```

**where the first bracket symbolizes the locations of a row in the matrix and each location is in it's own bracket within the row?**

In this example the first bracket is the first row with a total of 3 coordinates, then a second bracket symbolizing the 2nd row with another 3 coordinates.

Comment: I did not downvote, but you might be missing a few commas.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of

```
locations.append(x)
```

You can do

```
locations.append([x])
```

This will append a list containing x.

So to do what you want build up the list you want to add, then append that list (rather than just appending the values). Something like:

```
 ##Some loop to go through rows
    row = []
    ##Some loop structure
        row.append([x,y])
    locations.append(row)
```

Comment: I found this to be the easiest solution. Thanks for you help!

Answer (score 3):

simple example

```
locations = []

for x in range(3):
    row = []
    for y in range(3):
        row.append([x,y])
    locations.append(row)

print locations
```

result:

```
[[[0, 0], [0, 1], [0, 2]], [[1, 0], [1, 1], [1, 2]], [[2, 0], [2, 1], [2, 2]]]
```

Answer (score 2):

Try something like:

```
def f(n_rows, n_cols):
    locations = [] # Empty list
    for row in range(n_rows):
        locations.append([]) # 'Create' new row
        for col in range(n_cols):
            locations[row].append([x, y])
    return locations
```

**Test**

```
n_rows = 3
n_cols = 3
locations = f(n_rows, n_cols)
for e in locations:
    print
    print e

>>> 

[[0, 0], [0, 1], [0, 2]]

[[1, 0], [1, 1], [1, 2]]

[[2, 0], [2, 1], [2, 2]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
locations = [[]]
row = locations[0]
row.append([x, y])
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't go through a matrix and just want to embed some lists on a list:

```
groupA = [1,2,3]
groupB = ['a','b','c']
pair = []
for x in range(3):
    pair.append([groupA[x],groupB[x]])

>>>:
[[1, 'a'], [2, 'b'], [3, 'c']]
```