# How to append a list into a list

Tags: python, list

I want to append something that will output like list1. a list inside a list, how do i do that?
I don't care how u put abc into a list, but I want to know how to put that list into list1, so that list1 can be a list inside a list.
I want the output to be like this

```
x = a,b,c
list1 = []
list1 = [[a,b,c],[a,b,c]]
```

Comment: Try `list1 = [1, 2, 3]`, then `list2 = [list1, list1]`.  That will give `[[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]` for `list2`.

Comment: You can also do `list2.append(list1)` to append `list1` to `list2`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python append lists into lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19664116/python-append-lists-into-lists)

Comment: Use `list1.append(list2)`

Answer (score 1):

The function "append" is used to add an object to the end of a list. Since a list is an object, if you append another list onto a list, the first list will be a single object at the end of the list.

```
my_list = ['a', 'b', 'c'] 
another_list = [1, 2, 3] 
my_list.append(another_list) 
print(my_list) 
= "['a', 'b', 'c', [1, 2, 3]]"
```

You get the same result using the syntax:

```
my_list = ['a', 'b', 'c'] 
new_list = [my_list, my_list, my_list] 
print(new_list) 
= "[['a', 'b', 'c'], ['a', 'b', 'c'], ['a', 'b', 'c']]"
```

The function "extend" iterates over its argument adding each element to the list and extending the list. The length of the list increases by number of elements added.

```
my_list = ['a', 'b', 'c'] 
another_list = [1, 2, 3] 
my_list.extend(another_list) 
print(my_list) 
= "['a', 'b', 'c', 1, 2, 3]
```

You can get the same result as extend using a simple sum between lists:

```
my_list = ['a', 'b', 'c'] 
another_list = [1, 2, 3] 
print(my_list + another_list) 
= "['a', 'b', 'c', 1, 2, 3]
```